# How to get free/busy information to unlock for "resource calendars" in Outlook with Exchange 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, shared-mailbox

So, I know Exchange 2003 isn't supported anymore, there's a migration going on longterm.  However for now, we have to do with what we have.

We created users dedicated to share calendars each representing a resource employees can "borrow", that part is working, can be automated (refusal, acceptance...).

However, the real issue is that I cannot seem to find a consistent way to get resource availability to show.  The users want to be able to see when they can "borrow" it or now, instead of sending an appointment and get a refusal/acceptance.

With my actual process, I can get it to work 10% of the time, like 5-15 minutes after I'm done setting it up, but I don't know what makes it work.

Yes, I tried outlook /cleanfreebusy and gpupdate /force and yes, I do change the # of months to show from 2 to 6 (needed to update)

Any ideas/insights please?

Comment: You don't have Scheduling Assistant tab? In Outlook 2013, it shows your free/busy schedule of all attendees. You should specify what version of Outlook client you are using as well. Perhaps some screenshots will help as its not clear to me what your main question is... What are the resource accounts being used for? Borrowing assets? Booking conference rooms?

Comment: Borrowing assets.

Outlook 2007 is used.

Problem is that Free/busy info of resources is all /////////////////////////////////// instead of shoting white/purple.

Comment: 1) Set up delegate account that automatically responds to meeting requests that come to resource mailboxes. Microsoft Outlook remains logged on to delegate account that handles the resource booking. 2) Set the default permission on the resource Calendar folder to Editor. With this option, everyone can update all appointment items from the resource account. 3) Give Editor permission to the individuals that have to update the appointment items from the resource Calendar folder. With this option, those people who have Editor permission can update all appointment items from the resource account.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing...just can't see free/busy of those delegates.